# How to keep repeating a program until a specific input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program to compute the average of a group of numbers entered (one at a time) by the user. Each group should end when the user enters the sentinel value '' (ENTER without input). Two consecutive sentinel values should quit the program. The number of each group should be displayed along side with their average:

This is my code :

```
x = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
lis = []
while x != '':
    lis.append(x)
if x == '':
    avg = sum(lis) / len(lis)
print(avg)
```

Comment: Please no `eval`. They made [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for you so you can allow people to input a ridiculous range of literal types without making `input` provide a Turing complete interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `input` into the loop:

```
x = None
lis = []
while x != '':
    x = input('Enter a number: ')
    if x != '':
        lis.append(int(x))
avg = sum(lis) / len(lis)
print(avg)
```

Also you don't need the `if` statement as `x` must be equal to `''` anyway so that the `while` loop terminates.

Comment: Almost, but that won't work as `x` will be `''` before the loop. Also the `eval` (which should better be `int` or `float`) needs to be applied to `x` only if it is not `''`.

Comment: Please for the love of all things holy, use ast.literal_eval on user input. Otherwise a user could input   *import shutil; shutil.rmtree('/')*

Comment: @willnx: Technically, `eval` defaults to only allowing expressions, but `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')` satisfies that requirement. I agree with the sentiment 100%.

Comment: @SalehAlswiti You have to end it using `""` since you are using `input`. If you want to be able to simply hit Enter, change it to `raw_input`

Comment: @willnx I wanted to only fix the broken part in the OP's code, but changed it to `int` anyway.

Comment: @Selcuk Wow, that one is new to me. I really hope it requires admin rights on a win system but not going to test it.